# Conditional probability of C given two independent events

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem, naive-bayes

Suppose that a machine depends on the working state of two components A and B.

1. If both $A$ and $B$ do not function then the probability (say $C$) of the machine to work is $0.3$
2. If both $A$ and $B$ work then $P(C) = 0.9$
3. If exactly one of $A$ or $B$ works then $P(C) = 0.5$

The probability of $A$ to work is $P(A) = 0.7$, while $P(B) = 0.8$. The working state of $A$ does not affect the state of $B$ and vice versa (I suppose this means that $A$ and $B$ are independent, right?). How can I calculate the probability of the machine to work or $P(C)$ ? And, additionally if the machine works, what is the possibility of both $A$ and $B$ work?

I suppose that 1-3 are the results of $P(C|A^{c} \cap B^{c}), P(C|A \cap B)$ and $P(C|A^{c}B \cup AB^{c})$ and $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B), P(A \cup B) = P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$ but still I cannot figure how to compute P(C) out of Bayes rule... For the latter, I understand that I have to compute $P(A \cap B|C)$, but still I need $P(C)$. What am I missing? 
It's been two days that I am writing around equations but still nothing! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *three* events $A\cap B, A^c\cap B^c$, and $(A^c\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)$ are a *partition* of the sample space, and thus you can use the law of total probability to get
$$\begin{align}
P(C) &= P(C\mid A\cap B)P(A\cap B)\\
& +P(C\mid A^c\cap B^c)P(A^c\cap B^c)\\
& + P(C\mid (A^c\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c))P((A^c\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c)).
\end{align}$$
You are *given* the three conditional probabilities on the right of this
equation, and you know how to compute $P(A\cap B)$ from the knowledge (or assumption) that $A$ and $B$ are independent. I will only hint that
$A^c$ and $B^c$ are independent, as are $A$ and $B^c$, and $A^c$ and 
$B$ independent events.  Finally, $P(A^c\cap B)\cup (A\cap B^c))
= P(A^c\cap B)+ P(A\cap B^c)$. Can you tell why?

Comment: I suppose the intersect of A, B and their complements is zero/void.

Comment: @JohnSarmas If $A$ and $B$ are independent events (meaning that $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$, then so are $A^c$ and $B^c$ independent events, meaning that $P(A^c\cap B^c) = P(A^c)P(B^c)$. Also, $A^c$ and $B$ are independent events meaning that $P(A^c\cap B) = P(A^c)P(B)$ and so on and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I use $B^c$ to denote the event that $B$ does not work.
\begin{align*}
P(C) &= P(C \cap A \cap B) + P(C \cap A \cap B^c) + P(C \cap A^c \cap B) + P(C \cap A^c \cap B^c).
\end{align*}

For each of the terms, you can rewrite in terms of the conditional probabilities. E.g.,
$$P(C \cap A \cap B) = P(C \mid A \cap B) \cdot P(A \cap B)=P(C \mid A \cap B) \cdot P(A)\cdot P(B)$$